# How to scale MongoDB based analytics up to millions events per day?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, analytics

Regarding my previous question ( [How to quickly build large scale analytics server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401460/how-to-quickly-build-large-scale-analytics-server)
) I'm now feeding my analytics data to MongoDB - Every event (with bunch of metadata) gets their own document in views collection.

However, now I've hit the next roadblock: Now that inserts are done and analytics data is flowing, what would be the path of least resistance to do runs against that data? The idea is that once that data is sharded, the specific views would run mapReduces (say all events with specific ID one month back).

So, my question is: As I'm quite new with MongoDB, what are the steps I would need to do to get those mapReduces as fast as possible? Should I structure the raw data differently or is the one document per event correct? Are there Mongo specific tricks that I can do to make things flow faster when running against dataset that gets millions of inserts per day?

I would prefer to keep my technology stack as simple as possible (Node.js + MongoDB), so I'd prefer if things could be done without introducing extra technology (like say Hadoop).

Example document of a event:

```
{
    id: 'abc',
    ip: '1.1.1.1',
    type: 'event1',
    timestamp: 1234,
    metadata: {
        client: 'client1'
    }
}
```

All main aggregations will be ID centric, analysing events in said ID, the most used being get all events with said ID for the last month. Minor aggregations would be grouping things with metadata (how many percents used client1 vs. client2 etc.). All the aggregations will be system defined, so users can't set them by themselves, at this point at least. Thus, as far as I understand, the sharding should be done through ID, as big majority of the aggregations will be ID centric? Also, this should mean that the most recent events on any given ID are always in memory as Mongo keeps the latest stuff in memory and only dumps the overflow to disk.

Also, real time is not a requirement. Although, ofc it would be nice. :P

Edit: Added example data

Edit: Title should have been "...per day" not "...per page" + more spec about the aggregation sets

Comment: OK, so what aggregation tasks do you need to do with that schema?

Comment: Added bit more info about the aggregations

Comment: regarding sharding via ID. probably very bad, very low cardinality if lots of events have same id. u need something with high enough cardinality that mongodb can split the collection into small enough chunks to move around the shards. read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-internals/#sharding-internals-shard-keys

Comment: Ah, true. High traffic IDs vs low traffic IDs. But that in turn will make the queries slower, as data for single ID will be spread between shards, thus forcing the real time (or near real time) out of the gate. So, that in turn, would mean that in order to have fast responses for "events for last month" I would need to have a "rawdata" collection (where all events are inserted), which is then periodically crunched into ID specific collections?

Comment: too many questions on this question! ;)

Comment: Hehe. Yeah. I'm just trying to figure this thing out so that I can start building it to the right direction from the beginning and add those features "on the go". Ie. at the beginning I'll insert the raw data to the raw collection and at the same time preprocess it to the processed collections, where each id would have their data already processed. Then later on, when moving to high traffic IDs, I would just remove the preprocessing from the insertion and process the data in batches periodically. Thus scaling to the target of (hundreds of) millions of inserts per day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the other answer with my own flavour; map reduce is a solid option for a lot of your processing. Make no mistake, map reduce will be a vital core of your analytics if you do it fully.

The best sort of MR is an incremental one which builds things like archival statistics on certain events and people so as to shrink the overall database size and working set size of pulling out all that old, dusty data.

As for realtime usage, I have found (from many dicussions on the subject in early days of MongoDB in the Google User group) the best way is to pre-aggregate your data so that a simple linear query like: `db.some_preaggregated_data.find({date: {$gt, $lt}})` will get your results. This eases the sharding of the data and also the ranging over it, not to mention your working set size. Overall giving a much more performant operation.

I would recommend one thing:- don't go into the aggregation framework or complex queries if you really expect this to scale fully in realtime. It will start to create too much work on such a hugely expansive data set. You will need the full lock, working set etc on your side using simple `find()` queries to satisfy your needs across a big table format normally.

Comment: Yeah, full real time is not an prerequisite, near real time would be nice, and not-real-time-at-all goes as well. :)

Comment: @crappish Yea MR and AF wouldn't be near realtime on such data. MR would be more for building near realtime data into a efficiently storable format since the realtime data would not be efficient in terms of space etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Steps to get mapreduce as fast as possible:

- optimize your data so you have as much as possible in-memory. going to disk 'kills' (makes it really slow for) everything! (please see comments below on why I'd advise to not use mapreduce!)

> Should I structure the raw data differently ?

- if your number of dimensions that you aggregate upon are known and limited, then why not store & increment your aggregates on insertion? rather than query for it? (obviously this puts more load/processing on insertion) [MongoDB documentation on pre-aggregating patterns](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/)

> Are there Mongo specific tricks that I can do to make things flow faster when running against dataset that gets millions of inserts per day?

- sharding scales your writes. if a single node is loaded, add another. pick an appropriate shard key that enables balanced writes (one shard doesnt get all the writes)

Other things to consider:

MapReduce is slow and not suitable for online operations. Its a batch processing framework. It is also single-threaded, as the JS engine is. It also has overhead in translating to/from JS. I use the aggregation framework to get around these limits and have found it to be much faster and more scalable than using the mongodb mapreduce commands.

If performing either mapreduce or aggregation framework operations, try to get as much of your active dataset in-memory! going to disk kills performance for either. I found the mongodb notes on a [right-balanced index](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=right-balanced+index) invaluable to keeping our working set in-memory.

Comment: +1. But I think for the volumes he's talking about, AF will be too slow to be usable in real-time as well.

Comment: writes to master, AF on secondaries... then all that is happening on secondaries is replication. assume, when OP says 'last month' that querying is on the historical, non-changing part of collection. also assuming following mongodb best ops practices with 1 primary, 2 secondaries :)

Comment: Yeah, the end product would be historical queries. So, I would then have one master ("raw data") db, which would then be (real time/periodically) processed into secondary databases with say ID specific documents?

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce won't be quick. It uses the JavaScript engine for one thing, so the more code you need to run to query your data the slower it will be. The more you can leverage the native DB engine with indexes the better.
Can you provide some examples of what your data structure might look like?

Comment: The reduce code probably won't be too complicated, just reducing simple data with predefined parameters. Think of Google Analytics views; group things together by said metric and durations.

Comment: That won't be quick either for millions of documents. So if it can't be done in real-time, it might as well be done in MR, which also has the added bonus of being able to cache results and incrementally add. The net effect of that would be good enough for near real time.

Comment: What do you mean by MR caching? Is there some sort of automatic caching in MapReduce or do you just mean cache them "by hand"?

Comment: There's support for caching the 'output' as well as "Incremental" which means that if your aggregate queries are cumulative, you can just add the new data as you go along to the output collection. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Outputoptions

Comment: It's a good way to manage calculating as you go along so your results are always ready and available. You can't do this with AF yet.

Comment: I agree incremental MR is a solid option over af in this case, of course the best option in my opinion that I have found from actually doing this is to pre-aggregate your data into the format you need it, that way you just do a simple find on your data and BAM you have everything you need, adding sharding for 10's of millions of users is easy as well. You cna also add the time bucket theory to pre-aggregate further into actual full graph structures you just pull from the db.